# How to get&set value with Google scripts in first free row?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Heyo, I'm trying to get the value from "S2" from the "Crafting" Sheet and paste it into the next free row on the "Kurse" sheet. My code is not working for some reason. What am I doing wrong?

```
function kurse() {
var sourceSheet =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Crafting");
var wert = sourceSheet.getRange('S2').getValue();
var destSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Kurse");
var lastRow = destSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
destSheet.getRange(lastRow).setValue(wert);

}
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function kurse() {
var sourceSheet =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Crafting");
var wert = sourceSheet.getRange('S2').getValue();
var destSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Kurse");
var lastRow = destSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
destSheet.getRange(lastRow,1).setValue(wert);//added a column number

}
```